# A lot of errors and problems with classes and constructors

Tags: c++, arrays, class, struct, dynamic

Here is the code for file "lib.h"

```
/**
 * @file lib.h
 * @brief Файл с определением функций для решения заданий из лабораторной работы №23(unready)
 *
 * @author Taradai S.V.
 * @version 0.0
 * @date 19-май-2021
 */
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <cstdio>
 struct BirdHome{
   int HomeArea;
   int HomeHeight;
   int HomeFeederQuantity;
   bool HomeHasNest;
   BirdHome();
   BirdHome(int homearea, int homeheight, int feederquant, bool nest);
 };

class Bird{
  private:
    bool IsRinged;
    std::string Specie;
    int BirdAge;
    std::string Gender;
    struct BirdHome home;
  public:
    Bird();
    Bird(const Bird& copy);
    Bird(bool ring,std::string spec, int age,std::string gend, struct BirdHome hinfo);
    ~Bird();
    void set_IsRinged(const bool ring);
    void set_Specie(const std::string spec);
    void set_BirdAge(const int age);
    void set_Gender(const std::string gend);
    void set_BirdHome(const struct BirdHome hinfo);
    bool get_IsRinged()const;
    std::string get_Specie()const;
    int get_BirdAge()const;
    std::string get_Gender()const;
    struct BirdHome get_BirdHome()const;
};

class Array{
  private:
    Bird** arr;
    int size;
    int maxsize;
  public:
    Array();
    ~Array();
    Bird& getBird(int index)const;
    void Showall() const;
    void ShowBird(Bird bird)const;
    void addBird(const Bird& bird);
    void removeBird(int index)const;
};
```

Here is the code for file "lib.cpp"

```
/**
 * @file lib.c
 * @brief Файл с реализацией функций для решения заданий из лабораторной работы №23(unready)
 *
 * @author Taradai S.V.
 * @version 0.0
 * @date 19-маЙ-2021
 */
#include "lib.h"
BirdHome::BirdHome{

}
BirdHome::BirdHome(int homearea, int homeheight, int feederquant, bool nest)
  : HomeArea(homearea),
  HomeHeight(homeheight),
  HomeFeederQuantity(feederquant),
  HomeHasNest(nest){

}

Bird::Bird(){

}

Bird::Bird(const Bird& copy)
  : IsRinged(copy.IsRinged),
  Specie(copy.Specie),
  BirdAge(copy.BirdAge),
  Gender(copy.Gender),
  home(copy.home.HomeArea,copy.home.HomeHeight,copy.home.HomeFeederQuantity,copy.home.HomeHasNest){

}

Bird::Bird(bool ring,std::string spec, int age,std::string gend, struct BirdHome hinfo)
:IsRinged(ring),
Specie(spec),
BirdAge(age),
Gender(gend),
home(hinfo){

}

Bird::~Bird(){

}

void Bird::set_IsRinged(const bool ring){
  IsRinged=ring;
}

void Bird::set_Specie(const std::string spec){
  Specie=spec;
}

void Bird::set_BirdAge(const int age){
  BirdAge=age;
}

void Bird::set_Gender(const std::string gend){
  Gender=gend;
}

void Bird::set_BirdHome(const struct BirdHome hinfo){
  home.HomeArea=hinfo.HomeArea;
  home.HomeHeight=hinfo.HomeHeight;
  home.HomeFeederQuantity=hinfo.HomeFeederQuantity;
  home.HomeHasNest=hinfo.HomeHasNest;
}

bool Bird::get_IsRinged()const{
  return IsRinged;
}

std::string Bird::get_Specie()const{
  return Specie;
}

int Bird::get_BirdAge()const{
  return BirdAge;
}

std::string Bird::get_Gender()const{
  return Gender;
}

struct BirdHome Bird::get_BirdHome()const{
  return home;
}

Array::Array():size(0){
  birds=new Bird*[maxsize];
}

Array::~Array(){
  for(int i=0;i<maxsize;i++){
    delete birds[i];
  }
  delete[] birds;
}

Bird& Array::getBird(int index)const{
  return *birds[index];
}

void Array::Showall() const{
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    printf("\nBirds %d",i+1);
    ShowBird(getBird(i));
  }
}

void Array::ShowBird(Bird bird)const{
  printf("\n\tIs the birds ringed:%s\n\tThe bird's name specie:%s\n\tThe bird's age is:%d\n\tThe birdd's gender is:%s\n\tThe bird's home area(in square cm) is:%d\n\tThe bird's home height(in cm) is:%d\n\tAmount of feeders in bird's home is:%d\n\tDoes the bird's home has nest:%s",
bird.get_IsRinged()?"true":"false",
bird.get_Specie().c_str(),
bird.get_BirdAge(),
bird.get_Gender().c_str(),
bird.get_BirdHome().HomeArea,
bird.get_BirdHome().HomeHeight,
bird.get_BirdHome().HomeFeederQuantity,
bird.get_BirdHome().HomeHasNest?"true":"false");
}

void Array::addBird(const Bird& bird){
  if(size<maxsize){
    birds[size]=new Bird(bird);
    size++;
  }else{
    printf("\nThe limit is exceeded");
  }
}

void Array::removeBird(int index)const{
  delete birds[index];
  while (index<size){
    birds[index]=birds[index+1];
    index++;
  }
  size--;
  birds[index]=nullptr;
}
```

Here is the code for file "main.cpp"

```
/**
 * @file main.c
 * @brief Файл с демонстрацией решения заданий из лабораторной работы №23(unready)
 *
 * @author Taradai S.V.
 * @version 0.0
 * @date 19-май-2021
 */
#include "lib.cpp"
int main(){
  Array birds;
  birds.addBird(Bird(true,"False",5,"Male",BirdHome(100,50,3,false)));
  birds.addBird(Bird(false,"Crane",12,"Female",BirdHome(100,100,1,true)));
  birds.addBird(Bird(false,"Griffin",36,"Male",BirdHome(500,200,10,true)));
  birds.Showall();
  printf("\nThat is what we've found at the index 2:");
  birds.ShowBird(birds.getBird(2));
  printf("\nNow we'll delete the bird at the index 1");
  birds.removeBird(1);
  printf("This is what we got from it:");
  birds.Showall();
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the code for file "Makefile"

```
all:clean prep compile run format

clean:
    rm -rf dist
prep:
    mkdir dist


compile:main.bin test.bin


main.bin:
    clang++ -g  -I./src ./src/main.cpp -o ./dist/main.bin

    
test.bin:
    clang++ -g ./test/test.cpp -o ./dist/test.bin

format:
    doxygen Doxyfile
```

Well, this program should be working in a following way: we have an dynamic array of elements of class "Bird" which has 4 characteristics for an element and also a structure "BirdHome" that conatins 4 characteristics for current element. When running this program you will automatically initialise three elements in array with a constuctor with arguments(i have also a default contsructor and a copying one, but now they aren't needed). then it prints all of them and then you are shown an element with specific index and then you delete an element with the specific index. and then you are shown the contents of this array. but i got 13 error and i don't really know how to fix them. i just tried to rewrite somebody's code, but with my elements, but got this errors:

```
In file included from ./src/main.cpp:9:
./src/lib.cpp:11:11: error: qualified reference to 'BirdHome' is a constructor name rather than a type in this context
BirdHome::BirdHome{
          ^
./src/lib.cpp:11:19: error: expected unqualified-id
BirdHome::BirdHome{
                  ^
./src/lib.cpp:92:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'birds'
  birds=new Bird*[maxsize];
  ^
./src/lib.cpp:97:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'birds'
    delete birds[i];
           ^
./src/lib.cpp:99:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'birds'
  delete[] birds;
           ^
./src/lib.cpp:103:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'birds'
  return *birds[index];
          ^
./src/lib.cpp:127:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'birds'; did you mean 'bird'?
    birds[size]=new Bird(bird);
    ^~~~~
    bird
./src/lib.cpp:125:33: note: 'bird' declared here
void Array::addBird(const Bird& bird){
                                ^
./src/lib.cpp:127:10: error: type 'const Bird' does not provide a subscript operator
    birds[size]=new Bird(bird);
    ~~~~~^~~~~
./src/lib.cpp:135:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'birds'
  delete birds[index];
         ^
./src/lib.cpp:137:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'birds'
    birds[index]=birds[index+1];
    ^
./src/lib.cpp:137:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'birds'
    birds[index]=birds[index+1];
                 ^
./src/lib.cpp:140:7: error: cannot assign to non-static data member within const member function 'removeBird'
  size--;
  ~~~~^
./src/lib.cpp:134:13: note: member function 'Array::removeBird' is declared const here
void Array::removeBird(int index)const{
~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./src/lib.cpp:141:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'birds'
  birds[index]=nullptr;
  ^
```

Can you please help me solve them?

Comment: Well the first error is due to missing parentheses: `BirdHome::BirdHome{` --> `BirdHome::BirdHome () {`  and `Array` has no member named `birds`.

Comment: Wow,you really helped me. i forgot that i made a ```Bird** arr``` instead of ```Bird** birds```

Comment: My advice is to start reading the errors from the top. Many times a single problem can trigger multiple errors.

Comment: drescherjm, i tried to read them but i couldn't find what they were talkink about. to cou a long story short, just fixing them by the advice of G.M, the only 1 left:```./src/lib.cpp:140:7: error: cannot assign to non-static data member within const member function 'removeBird' :size--;``` can you please say what should i do?

Comment: `void removeBird(int index)const;` you need to remove the `const` at the end if `removeBird()` is to make changes to the object.

Comment: `#include "lib.cpp"` Never include .cpp files. .h files are suitable for inclusion.

Comment: The target `main.bin` in Makefile is not corresponding the output file `-o ./dist/main.bin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that original Array that must've contained a dynamic array of class "Bird" doesn't have any of it. because it was like this

```
Bird** arr
```

and by changing it to the normal using in the code, like this one

```
Bird** birds
```

The program started working normally